# SQL convert compatibility matrix into mapping table (columns into rows)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

[image]

I want to convert the matrix to this format:

[image]

where the new mapping table represents the compatibility between a set of options and a set of models that use those options, and the numeric values represent the price of an option for that specific model.

Bare in mind that this is just a small sample from a much bigger table, so the query needs to be more or less dynamic and not hardcoded based on the number of options or models provided in this example.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UnPivot or Gordon's answer would be more performant, but here is an option that will "dynamically" unpivot your data or query without actually using dynamic SQL.

**Example**

```
Select A.OptionID
      ,ModelName  = C.Item
      ,Price      = C.Value
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item  = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = a.value('.','varchar(max)') --<< Change to desired datatype
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
                 Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('OptionID','OtherFieldsToExclude')
             ) C
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: . . I don't think `unpivot` is more performant than `outer apply`.  Do you have a reference on that?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I actually prefer your approach..  I was just saying that my answer would not be as performant as yours or unpivot.  This approach just removes the need to list all the fields (except the key ones).  Furthermore, you can "dynamically" unpivot virtually any table or query/

Comment: @GordonLinoff Also, this approach excludes NULLs.  That may be good or bad depending on one's needs.

Answer (score 1):

I like to do this using `outer apply`:

```
select v.*
from t outer apply
     (values (option_id, 'model1', model1),
             (option_id, 'model2', model2),
             (option_id, 'model3', model3)
     ) v(option_id, model_name, price);
```

You would just add more rows to the `values` list for each item you want in the final table.

You can also do this using `union all`, `cross join`/`case`, and `unpivot`.

However, this method uses lateral joins, and these are very powerful for other purposes as well.  This is worthwhile syntax to master.

EDIT:

I'm not really sure what "dynamic" means in this context.  You table has columns or it doesn't.  You can use dynamic SQL to generate the code based on the input parameters or the layout of a single table.  It would follow the same logic as above.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your reply. I'm gonna try this. What I meant by dynamic was that it would be great to have a query that works no matter how many models I have (there are plenty actually). But if it's not possible this is (way) better than nothing! Regards