# How to Un Pivot the Table With Date Headers in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following Temp table with Date Header How to UnPivot this Table

[image]
[image: I need This type result]

I need Like This type result

Comment: Please read this:  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are your expected results? Images are useless as sample data for a SQL question. [Forum Etiquette: how to post sample data for a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/). Please *try* to put some effort in when posting a question. Thanks. :)

Comment: Here's an option without using Dynamic SQL  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46133006/sql-convert-compatibility-matrix-into-mapping-table-columns-into-rows/46133104#46133104

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following script:

```
  SELECT [s#no], [Emp#ID], [Name], [Date], [Shiftid]
    FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM table_name) SRC
    UNPIVOT
   ([Date] FOR [Emp#ID] 
    IN ([01-Mar-18], [02-Mar-18], [03-Mar-18], [04-Mar-18], [05-Mar-18])
   ) UNPVT;
```

Comment: It's Working Fine But Some Column have a empty Date ,So Get This Error   --- "   Msg 8167, Level 16, State 1, Line 38
The type of column "17-Mar-18" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list."  ---        What I do ?..

Comment: This solutions works only when you know the name of all the columns in the pivot and they are static - they have to be all included in the IN clause. An great example is the months in a year: they never change so they are static. If your dates (04-Mar-2018, ...) may change over time, you should use the solution that @Nishant Gupta submitted. In order to solve the problem you mentioned, just add [17-Mar-18] in the () of the IN clause.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to your Problem:

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot 
  = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
           FROM sys.columns c
           WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('table') 
           for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query 
  = 'select sno,EmpId, Name, Date, Value
     from table
     unpivot
     (
        Date 
        FOR EmpId IN ('+ @colsunpivot +')
     ) u'

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

I used dynamic query since if you don't know how much columns are there in your table.
You can also use below static query :

```
SELECT sno, EmpId, Name, Date, Value
FROM 
   (SELECT *
   FROM table) p
UNPIVOT
   (Date FOR EmpId IN 
      (01-Mar-18,02-Mar-18,03-Mar-18,04-Mar-18,05-Mar-18)
)AS unpvt;
```